# Como combinar diferentes dataframes de diferentes dimensiones python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Esto es lo que tengo:

data=
        Fecha          0     1     2     3  ...  23    promdia

```
  1995-01-01      43    43.2  44    43      41      #
  1995-01-02      #      #     #     #       #      #
      .
      .
      .
  2018-12-31      #      #     #     #       #      #
```

ipc= 
     Año   indice

```
 1995     20.2
 1996      #
   .       #
   .       #
   .       #
 2017     101.2
 2018     104.4
```

Como pueden notar, ["Fecha"] es un datetime, pero en un dataframe es %Y-%m-%d y en el otro es %Y. Y tambien ambas son de diferente tamaño

Necesito algo como esto.

newdataframe= 
              Fecha          0     1     2     3  ...  23    promdia  Año    indice

```
        1995-01-01      43    43.2  44    43      41      #      1995     20.2
        1995-01-02      #      #     #     #       #      #      1995     20.2
            .
            .
            .
        2018-12-30      #      #     #     #       #      #      2018     104.4 
        2018-12-31      #      #     #     #       #      #      2018     104.4
```

Incluso sin ["Año"] en newdataframe

Thanks

Comment: Estas en SO en español por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: ¿De que tipo son tus columna `año` y `Fecha`? (`print(data.Fecha.dtype , ipc.Año.dtype)`

Comment: ambas son datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero vamos a crear un ejemplo reproducible basado en tu ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Fecha": ("1995-01-01", "1995-01-02", "1999-08-24",
               "2000-03-21", "2018-10-13", "2018-12-31"
               ),
     "1": (4, 6, 7, 13, 23, 17),
     }
)

ipc = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Año": (1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2017, 2018),
     "indice": (20.2, 40.3, 50.2, 70.4, 101.2, 104.4),
     }
)
data["Fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Fecha"], format='%Y-%M-%d', exact=True).dt.normalize()
ipc["Año"] = pd.to_datetime(ipc["Año"], format='%Y').dt.normalize()
```

Partiendo de la base de que ambas columnas son de tipo fecha (`Datetime64`, `<M8`, `>M8`, ...) podemos simplemente aplicar `pandas.DataFrame.merge`. La clave está en aplicarlo sobre el atributo `dt.year` de las columnas `Fecha` y `Año`:

```
res = data.merge(
    ipc["indice"],
    how="left",
    left_on=data["Fecha"].dt.year,
    right_on=ipc["Año"].dt.year
    )

res.drop('key_0', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> res
>
>        Fecha   1  indice
> 0 1995-01-01   4    20.2
> 1 1995-01-02   6    20.2
> 2 1999-01-24   7    50.2
> 3 2000-01-21  13    70.4
> 4 2018-01-13  23   104.4
> 5 2018-01-31  17   104.4
> ```